# Authentication issue while running website application in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am new to .Net framework.I am using Visual Studio 2012 express.Actually I have to expose an webservice and host into IIS7.So I created the New website and choosed the WCF webservice in visual studio and wrote the Contract.and I am using the Rassoc.Samples.BasicAuthenticationModule for authentication.In IIS manager I disabled the Anonymous auth.
Now when I browse the website its ask me credentials (Credentials are stored in user.xml).when i provided the same its fine.But when I am clicking on Service.svc, its giving me below error:-

**> [NotSupportedException: Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.]**

when I enabled the anonymous in IIS manager then every thing is working fine.On clicking Service.svc .it gives the WSDL.

I don't know what to do to get this wsdl.I cant enable the ananaymous in IIS manager.

Please suggest me solution...(how to enable the auth for this service.may be in web.config)

Thanks in Advance.